# Java txt to sqlite database data transfer how can be faster

Tags: optimization

I wrote a java program about transfering a txt file to a sqlite db but it takes really more time there are about 83000 data (200 data takes about 1 minute).
how can i increase transfering speed. İ tried adding arraylist than get but its not change

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class NewMain {

public static Connection connect() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        String url1 = "jdbc:sqlite:c:/Users/sozdemir/Desktop/sozluk.db";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url1);
        String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS KELIMELER (Kelime PRIMARYKEY NOT NULL);"; 
        Statement s  = conn.createStatement();
        s.execute(sql1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
    return conn;
    }

public void Verigir(String kelime){
String sql = "INSERT INTO KELIMELER (kelime) VALUES(?)";
    try (Connection conn = this.connect();
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql)
            ){
        statement.setString(1, kelime);
        statement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
/*    connect();*/

    NewMain app = new NewMain();    
    String kelime = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    int adet;
    adet= 0;
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C://Users//sozdemir//Desktop//ozluk.txt"));
    while ((kelime=in.readLine()) !=null) {
        app.Verigir(kelime);
    adet +=1;
        System.out.println(81742 - adet);
    }    
}
```

}

Comment: done any profiling to see WHERE the slowdown is? maybe your code is running blazing fast and only takes 0.000001% of runtime, and the other 99.999999% is waiting for sqlite.

Comment: insering to sqlite part is decreasing time but i dont know how can i increase

Comment: don't prepare a statement each time, then. one of the MAJOR points of a prepare statement is that the sql parsing/compilation overhead is only done ONCE, then you just fill in the placeholders as many times as necessary.

Comment: I can use arraylist once to add them all to arraylist but can I use this array list include a statement once time. If yes how can pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some hints:

1. Use a single prepareStatement
2. Put everything inside a transaction
3. Use PRAGMA synchronous = OFF and PRAGMA journal_mode = OFF

This will give you very fast inserts.